# How to update an HTML table content without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an HTML table that is fetching some data from the database and also a button for deleting selected records .

The table looks like that:

```
name phone links
john 6562  link1
           link2
           link3
________________
jim 7682   link1
________________
... ...    ....
```

The code is something like that :

```
<form method="post" action="#">
 <table>                    
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Phone</th>
      <th scope="col">Links</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>   
    <?php
       echo "<tr>";
        echo  "<th><input type='checkbox'></th>";
        echo "<th>".$row['name']."</th>";
        echo "<td>".$row['phone']."</td>";
        echo "<td>";
         echo '<a  href=""></a><br/>';
        echo "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
     ?>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" value="Delete Selected" name="delete"/>
</form>
```

Now when I delete any record of the table and the database , I have to refresh the page to see that it's deleted .
What I want is when I click the delete button , The record is deleted and the table is updated with a successful message at the top of the page, Is that possible ?

Comment: Absolutely possible - and a lot of ways to do it.  Angular is probably the most popular at the moment.  But you can directly manipulate the DOM, or use jQuery to manipulate the DOM...  Just to name three ways to do it.

Comment: Yes that is possible. You can use ajax to fetch the table from your php then use it to update the DOM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in html

```
<tbody id="table-body">
    <?php include 'tableBody.php';?>
</tbody>
```

in your button function

```
$.get("tableBody.php", function(data) {
    $("#table-body").html(data);
});
```

When the button function is trigger, it will fire up the AJAX GET request to the `tableBody.php`, and then use its content to update the `<tbody>` with id `table-body`.

Comment: thank you it worked successfully

Comment: I have a problem with this one, upon refreshing using a button, it will not retain the original style of the table.